# Access TFS with user crendential coming from Windows Integrated Authentication

Tags: .net, iis, tfs, windows-authentication

I have write a web application that access Team Foundation Server on premise. It use windows integrated authentication since it is deployed inside of corporate network.

But I found every time when a user connect, IIS is able to pass the user info to my application, but my application can not pass this info to access TFS. There is an access denied exception thrown.

Here is what I've done to my web config: I enabled windows authentication, I enabled impersonation. What else is missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting a standard Active Directory double hop authentication issue. If you run your app on the same server as TFS you will not his this but the authentication token you have is scoped to the server without a Kerberos token.

You need to configure the correct SPN (Service Principal Names) in Actives Directory with the SetSPN command to allow the service account that you are running under to access TFS with a passthrough token.

Comment: thanks for your reply! Let me ask more details as I'm not familiar within this field. I found without any modification of my web config mentioned in the question, I can access TFS through my web app if I visit the app through the hosting machine. Do you know why?

Comment: That's single hop. It's like running in debug mode, you are directly authenticated on the server. Double hop is where you are workstation->webserver->tfsserver.